# How can I write a function that will set the value of a variable inside a parent object?

Tags: javascript

I created the following object:

```
app.state = {
    message: {
        clear: function() {
            message.error = null;
            message.text = null;
        },
        alert: function(text) {
            message.error = true;
            message.text = text;
        },
        set: function(text) {
            message.error = null;
            message.text = text;
        },
        error: null,
        text: null,
    }
}
```

However when I call app.state.message.set('abc') I get an error saying message is undefined. Can someone tell me how I can make this work? Is there some way I can set the parent object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.state = {
    message: {
        clear: function() {
            this.error = null;
            this.text = null;
        },
        alert: function(text) {
            this.error = true;
            this.text = text;
        },
        set: function(text) {
            this.error = null;
            this.text = text;
        },
        error: null,
        text: null,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    app.state = {
    message: {
        clear: function() {
            this.error = null;
            this.text = null;
        },
        alert: function(text) {
            this.error = true;
            this.text = text;
        },
        set: function(text) {
            this.error = null;
            this.text = text;
        },
        error: null,
        text: null,
    }
}
```

It's a scope issue. Change your "message"'s to "this". At the scope of the functions within the message object, the object "method" is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this`. In that context, `this` is equal to `message`.

```
app.state = {
    message: {
        clear: function() {
            this.error = null;
            this.text = null;
        },
        alert: function(text) {
            this.error = true;
            this.text = text;
        },
        set: function(text) {
            this.error = null;
            this.text = text;
        },
        error: null,
        text: null,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use closures:

```
app.state = new (function(){
  var 
    error = null,
    text  = null;
  this.message = {
    clear: function() {
        error = null;
        text = null;
    },
    alert: function(newText) {
        error = true;
        text = newText;
    },
    set: function(newText) {
        error = null;
        text = newText;
    },
    getError: function() {
        return error;
    },
    getText: function() {
        return text;
    }
  };
})();
```